# Getting a syntax error when trying the IN operator with a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Having the following scheme

```
employees

 - id

coordinations

 - id

employee_coordinations

 - id
 - employee_id
 - coordination_id

activities

 - id
 - name
 - state
 - organized_by_id
```

I try to make a query where I get a list of activities that meet the following conditions

1. The state of the activity must be equal to notified
2. The organizer of the activity must be among the list of
   coordinations to which an employee belongs

I created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d87aa6/9) to facilitate their collaboration

I understand I should use the in operator with a subquery that returns the id of the coordinations to which an employee belongs

The query that I tried is the following:

```
select
  a.id,
  a.name,
  a.organized_by_id
from
  activities a
where
  a.state = 'notified'
and
  a.organized_by_in in (
    select
      ec.coordination_id
    from
      employee_coordinations ec
        inner join
      coordinations c
        on
      ec.coordination_id = c.id
        inner join
      employees e
        on
      e.id = ec.employee_id
    where
      e.id = 2;
  );
```

But I get a syntax error.

If for the use case my approach to solve it is incorrect, I thank you for your advice

I thank you for your time and help

Comment: You've completed some of the steps, but see this anyway: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Too many semicolons. Remove this one `e.id = 2;`. And change `a.organized_by_in` to `a.organized_by_id`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles beat me to it.  In the future, you can check basic syntax issues with a sql checker like this one: https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Comment: I think is working as expected now, removing the ; and fixing a typo `organized_by_id` insetad of `organized_by_in`

Comment: change 'a.organized_by_in' to 'a.organized_by_id' in the first WHERE clause

Comment: Strawberry, thanks for the observation, I will keep it in mind

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d87aa6/19  2 changes were needed, both listed above (a semi colon, and a column name misspelled)